How do I make a slideshow popup with next/prev arrows within the image?
I want to make a popup with a slideshow but I have a problem, I can't get the naviagtion arrows be placed inside the image container, so when the website is resized they stay in the same place.
I want to move the navigation arrows here (Purple indicating where I want them to be)
Here's what I'd like it to look like
Website showing what I have right now
HTML Fragment:
<div id="popup" class="popup hidden">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <span id="closePopup" class="close">&times;</span>
    <button id="prevImage" class="nav-button">&lt;</button>
    <img id="popupImage" src="" alt="Project Image">
    <button id="nextImage" class="nav-button">&gt;</button>
    <div class="popup-text">
      <p id="popupName"></p>
      <p id="popupDescription"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS Fragment:
/* Popup */
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.popup-content {
  background-color: #494949;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 70vw;
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#popupImage {
  width: 55%; 
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 8%;
  position: relative;
}

#popupName {
  font-size: 3vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#popupDescription {
  font-size: 2vh;
}


/* Navigation Buttons */
.nav-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

#prevImage {
  left: 1.5%;
}

#nextImage {
  right: 1.5%;
}


Similar to how you placed the popup name and description into a containing div element, you can place the next/prev buttons and image into another div container and absolutely position the buttons relative to it instead of the overall content container.
Example:
<div id="popup" class="popup hidden">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <span id="closePopup" class="close">&times;</span>

    <div id="image-container">
      <button id="prevImage" class="nav-button">&lt;</button>
      <img
        id="popupImage"
        src="...."
        alt="Project Image"
      />
      <button id="nextImage" class="nav-button">&gt;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="popup-text">
      <p id="popupName">....</p>
      <p id="popupDescription">....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

...

.popup-content {
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #494949;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 70vw;
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  gap: 8%; /* <-- add "padding" here */
}

...

#popupImage {
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* margin-right: 8%; remove */
  position: relative;
}

...

#image-container {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

...


Note that because I don't have your complete HTML and CSS I had to omit, or change, some of image CSS to get it to render nicely in isolation. You may need to tweak your CSS styling a bit more as well.
